# CFTs describing branes

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry, yang-mills, branes

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.05057) section 3, the author describes how a $U(N) \;\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM theory can be coupled to 2 boundary 3D CFTs. Then the boundary CFT would describe the low-energy physics of $N$ semi-infinite D3-branes (in the 0123 directions) ending on stacks of D5-branes (in the 123456 directions) and NS5-branes (in the 123789 directions), with additional D3-branes stretched in the 3 direction between the D5s and NS5s.

When the 3D CFT is coupled to the $U(N) \;\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM theory does that mean that we have 2 theories, just combined together?